# Multiple process mongod --auth --bind_ip_all - Mongo with Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, memory, dump, mongodump

When I run this command on my debian server :

```
sudo docker exec -it production_mongo_1 mongodump --uri="mongodb://[URI]@localhost/[DB]" --out="/data/db"
```

all my `mongod --auth --bind_ip_all` processes start to consume a lot of memory on my server and don't come down after finishing the dump. I don't know how to solve this problem.

[htop screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUYDm.png)

I've already tried to understand the logs generated by mongodb (no results). I tried to modify my dump request without success either.

Comment: What are all these `mongod` instances doing?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti I don't know where they are coming from? maybe my docker-compose, a bad configuration? :  `mongo:
    image: mongo:6.0.2
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - $DATABASE_DIRECTORY:/data/db
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: "root"
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${MONGO_PASSWORD}"
    ports:
      - "${MONGO_PORT}:27017"
    networks:
      - app-network`

Comment: Running more than 2 `mongod` on a server usually points to a config problem or a design problem unless it is an academic setting where performance and maintainability are not issues.   You don't want `mongod` instances fighting with each other for memory, threads, and i/o.